# Organise Trac's 'Available Projects' page

Tags: trac

Does anyone know how to split the list of projects on the 'Available Projects' page into a list of active and archived projects? At the moment they are all listed together and I have a large number of projects so it is difficult to identify just the active projects.

I'm not a web developer or python expert so I would appreciate simple, easy-to-follow answers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project index [can be customized](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/1.1/TracInterfaceCustomization#ProjectList). You'll need a criteria for grouping the projects into active and archived. [Here](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.0.9/trac/web/main.py?marks=710-714#L684) you can see the variables that are listed for each project. You could add a value in the `config/trac.ini` file for each project, such as `[project] archived = true`, and read that value when rendering the project index in order to determine which group to list the project in - active vs. archived. The value can be read using `env.config.get('project', 'archived')`.

Here is a proof-of-concept.

Create 4 projects and set 2 of them as *archived*:

```
$ mkdir projects && cd projects
$ virtualenv pve
$ source pve/bin/activate
$ pip install trac
$ mkdir environments && cd environments
$ for i in `seq 1 4`; do
    trac-admin env$i initenv "Project $i" sqlite:db/trac.db
  done
$ trac-admin env3 config set project archived true
$ trac-admin env4 config set project archived true
```

Add the following in `projects/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/"
      xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <head>
    <title>Available Projects</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Active Projects</h1>
    <ul>
      <li py:for="project in projects"
          py:if="not project.env.config.get('project', 'archived')"
          py:choose="">
        <a py:when="project.href" href="$project.href"
           title="$project.description">$project.name</a>
        <py:otherwise>
          <small>$project.name: <em>Error</em> <br /> ($project.description)</small>
        </py:otherwise>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h1>Archived Projects</h1>
    <ul>
      <li py:for="project in projects"
          py:if="project.env.config.get('project', 'archived')"
          py:choose="">
        <a py:when="project.href" href="$project.href"
           title="$project.description">$project.name</a>
        <py:otherwise>
          <small>$project.name: <em>Error</em> <br /> ($project.description)</small>
        </py:otherwise>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Run TracStandalone:

```
$ cd projects
$ TRAC_ENV_INDEX_TEMPLATE=`pwd`/index.html tracd -r -p 8001 --env-parent-dir=environments
```

The result is:

[image: Project Index]

Comment: Great! Thank you RjOllos!

Comment: For those who are using fcgi, you need to add os.environ['TRAC_ENV_INDEX_TEMPLATE'] = "/path/to/template.html" to /usr/share/pyshared/trac/cgi-bin/trac.fcgi